# Python: Train a word2vec model using vectors as input

Tags: python, word2vec

I am using Python to train a word2vec model and get embeddings for each word in vocabulary. I used `gensim` to do this before, and I also notice that such model can be trained by tools like `TensorFlow`, `Theano`, and so on..

However, during these training processes, the inputs are just texts which are basically in `string` format, then the words will be mapped to `index` for training. In my case, I want to input `arrays` for training. These arrays, can be one-hot encoded vectors or other vectors after some designed manipulation.

So, is there existing tool which trains word2vec model by inputting vectors? If there is no such tools, any recommendation for me to learn so that I can write my own code?

Comment: Hey, i also want to do exactly same thing... did u find a way to do that ??

Comment: @Shweta Hey, I didn't find existing methods, so in the end I re-write a training  model by myself, which is basically based on original gensim word2vec.py model

Comment: can you please share the code with me... it will be really helpful for me...

Comment: @Shweta That's ok, could you give me an email address?

Comment: I have sent it to you, please check it

Comment: Thanks a lot @gladys0313